# Need different color of span in anchor for a:link, same for a:hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a link in which a span is embedded containing a "less than" arrow `<` followed by a `nbsp` and some text:

```
<a href=".."><span class="smallbutton">&lt;</span>&nbsp;back to overview</a>
```

I want the entire anchor to be gray text except for the `<` which should be white. The entire anchor should be orange text on hover but I can't get that to work... I wonder if it's possible just by using CSS, but I doubt it.

Styling (currently closest attempt):

```
.smallbutton {
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
}
.smallbutton:hover {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    color: inherit;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #FC930A !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #F7C41F !important;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The problem is, I expected the `!important` to override `white` but it doesn't...

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2GX2Y/

The colors that are on the `<` should be there when just hovering over the containing `<a>` tag, not just the `<` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you change

```
.smallbutton:hover
```

to

```
a:hover .smallbutton
```

then you'll have what you want. But I may have misunderstood the question.

Just let me know!

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/tRRRV/1/